# Trying to reorganize this PHP array so it's values are toghether by id and easily accesible later

Tags: php, sql, arrays, for-loop

First of all, I couldn't think of any better title, sorry if you find it inapropiate.

I have this function which task is to bring data from 2 databases, modify some of that data, and upload everything to an external API.

The first database `accounting` has

`subscriber_id | amount | zone_id`

stored in the table named `cdr`

The second db `billing` has stored inside the table `billing_zones` these values:

`zone_id | zone_name`

Everything I've done works fine, but the resulting array is not what I expected/wanted.

This is my code:

```php
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=accounting','user','password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}



$destinationId = 0;
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT a.`zone`, b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, SUM(b.`source_customer_cost`) AS total
    FROM `billing`.billing_zones a INNER JOIN cdr b 
    ON a.`id` = b.`source_customer_billing_zone_id` 
    WHERE destination_account_id = :destinationId 
    GROUP BY b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, a.`zone`');
$stmt->execute(array('destinationId' => $destinationId));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) { 
    $sanitizedData[$i] = array(
        0 => $data[$i][0],
        1 => $data[$i][1],
        2 => $data[$i][2]
    );
}

/*ATTEMPT TO MAKE THE ARRAY I WANTED - DIDN'T WORK*/
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) { 
    while ($sanitizedData[$i] == $sanitizedData[$i-1][1]) {
        $newArray[] = array_merge($sanitizedData[$i], $sanitizedData[$i-1]);
    }
}

var_dump($sanitizedData);
```

The result of the code above my `ATTEMPT` comment is a big array, I will show you a piece of it so you can understand better what I want to do:

```php
[1047]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "Llamadas Moviles nacionales"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "V30048086"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "460.440000"
  }
  [1048]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "Llamadas Premium 902 Nivel 1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "V30048086"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "87.301236"
  }
  [1049]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "Llamadas Fijos nacionales"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "W24154073"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "64.340367"
  }
  [1050]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "Llamadas Moviles nacionales"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "W24154073"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "116.480000"
  }
  [1051]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "Llamadas Premium 901 Nivel 1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "W24154073"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "62.559759"
  }
```

To clarify:

`array[n][0] is the aforementioned zone_name`

`array[n][1] is the subscriber_id - The id defining the customer`

`array[n][2] is the SUM() of the amount for that id in that zone.`

So the result is that for every id, there are several arrays for each zone.

What I want to do is to group those in a unique array like:

```php
[1051]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "W24154073"
    [1]=>
    string(28) "Llamadas Premium 901 Nivel 1"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "62.559759"
    [3]=>
    string(28) "Llamadas Moviles nacionales"
    [4]=>
    string(9) "116.480000"
    [5]=>
    string(28) "Llamadas Fijos nacionales"
    [6]=>
    string(9) "64.340367"
    .
    .
    . 
    If there were more
  }
```

As @Misorude pointed out in the comments, maybe using the subscriber_id as key for the main array would be a better solution:

```php
["W24154073"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "Llamadas Premium 901 Nivel 1"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "62.559759"
    [2]=>
    string(28) "Llamadas Moviles nacionales"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "116.480000"
    [4]=>
    string(28) "Llamadas Fijos nacionales"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "64.340367"
    .
    .
    . 
    If there were more
  }
```

This way, I could later access the array and fetch the info customer by customer, not having in mind how many zones they are in.

I don't know if this is all necessary or if I don't even need any of this to begin with, but I could not think about any way to do it. Maybe I have overthinked this a lot.

If you know how to turn the array I get into the array I want it would be great, but if there is another solution to pass the data easier than this, then please, bring me the light I need.

Thank you for the help, have a great weekend!

Comment: `$sanitizedData[$i] == $sanitizedData[$i-1][1]` would only be true for entries that have the same values in _all three_ sub-items this contains. I don’t see the point of your `$sanitizedData` array here in the first place - that is nothing but data you copied over 1:1, without any manipulation, directly from $data.

Comment: The top-level keys in that array you have shown, 1047, 1048, etc. - are those supposed to be IDs of anything, or is that just a normal, zero-based index, and what you showed was just a section from somewhere in the array?

Comment: Yeah I know, but I don't really see any way of doing it, so I had to start trying :P
-EDIT-
Sorry, I did not understand at first, the $sanitizedData comes from $data having duplicate rows, so I manually only choose one of them. @misorude

Comment: That's right, they are just the index, the actual id is inside the smaller array, position 1 always

Comment: Then what do you actually want to _group_ under? If 1051 in what you have shown as what you want is not an ID - then what determined that specifically _those_ records should appear in that particular entry?

Comment: @misorude oh you are right, damn, I guess that you understand better what I want to do than myself! 
I am going to apply some changes to the question right away, could you please explain me more about what I need to do here?

Comment: I am still not sure where those IDs are supposed to come from, your SELECT statement only returns three values, and from your description, all three of those seem to mean something different, none of them actually being that kind of ID? (1047, 1048, etc.)

Comment: Assuming your $row contained an ID _and_ those three values, you could basically do it simple as this, https://pastebin.com/WXkvYnKZ (I used “speaking” keys instead of numbers here, but the principle is the same.) `$data[$row['id']][] = …` adds a new element to the data array on the second level, using the ID as key on the first. If you do that three times with three different values for each record, then you will have repeating sets of such “threes” at the end, grouped under the ID value.

Comment: Basically, one is the customer's id or `W24154073` for example. The zone_name is kind of the fare to pay (for example in one 'zone' price can be 1, but in another zone price is 2) and last, is the total amount -> `id W24154073 has a total to pay of 62 in "Llamadas Premium 901 Nivel 1" zone, which has a certain price, but  "Llamadas Fijos nacionales" is a different zone with different pricing, so they have to be included separately` This way the customer knows how he is spending his money

Comment: This is all to create a bill, in which I inform the customer of the different payments he has to make. I wanted to group all the payments under the same id, and I think that you were right telling me to use the id as the array key, I am going to try it right away, i will inform here as soon as I'm done, thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: That should be achievable easily using the method I just described - example with row keys modified to macth your data, https://pastebin.com/fUS3QXrG [1] is the ID we group by, [0] and [2] are the actual data fields we insert under that.

Comment: @misorude It worked!! Damn!! I love you with my whole heart, I wish you a fantastic weekend and I hope you are terrified no more about using a product developed by me in the future <3

Comment: Great. I added a short answer (comments probably will get removed at some point, that often happens especially with extended discussions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of discussion and clarifying the requirement, this boiled down to inserting two data fields from each record into an array, grouped under an ID value from a third field.

This can be a achieved in quite a simple fashion, like this:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // $row[1] is the subscriber_id
    $data[$row[1]][] = $row[0]; // $row[0] is zone_name
    $data[$row[1]][] = $row[2]; // $row[2] is the sum amount
}
var_dump($data);
```

The “trick” here is to let PHP take care of the grouping, basically, by providing the grouping id as array key on the first level, `$data[$row[1]]`, and then simply appending new items under that on the second level, using `[] = …` syntax.